# repeat same procedure for n dataframes in R

Tags: r, loops, repeat

I have a problem with a procedure in R that I want to repeat for 100 databases that are equal, but refers to different categories of products.

My databases are named "df_01_Z0001", "df_01_Z0002", "df_01_Z0003", "df_01_Z0004", ..."df_01_Z0100". They have the same variables, but as I stated before they must be kept separated since they include values of different categories of products. I have this procedure:

```
df_01_Z0001 <- sqldf("SELECT a.*, b.ln_yval 
              FROM appo_01_t_all as a
              LEFT JOIN df_01_Z0001 as b 
              on a.week=b.week")
df_01_Z0001 <- df_01_Z0001[,-2]
df_01_Z0001 <- df_01_Z0001[order(df_01_Z0001$week),]

ts_df_01_Z0001 <- ts(df_01_Z0001$ln_yval, 
                freq=52)

mod_01_Z0001 <- HoltWinters(ts_df_01_Z0001, alpha = NULL, beta = NULL, gamma = NULL, seasonal = c("additive"))

fcst_tab_01_Z0001 <- predict(mod_01_Z0001, 4, prediction.interval = FALSE)
```

So it is a holtwinters model that works fine with a single database, but it is clear that I cannot write the code above for 100 times. The idea is that I only need to change "Z0001" with a parameter and write a loop (or I don't know how) in order to repeat this procedure for 100 databases. I don't know how to do it. I tried some loops but I didn't find out a solution.
Thank you for the help

Comment: So, it sounds like you want to create `n` different strings, one for each database. Is that where you are stuck? Or are you stuck with executing the whole thing `n` times?

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for the additional explanation. Suppose you have your `n` sqldf strings already. Write the above as a function doing everything you need to do for one of them. Then simply use e.g. `lapply` to execute the function for each string.

Comment: I am stuck with executing the whole thing n times. Unfortunately I have never used loop or other actions (maybe lapply()) so I don't know how to do the whole code changing only "Z0001", "Z0002", .... and so on

Comment: could you make an example? because I have never done it before

Comment: See the example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example:

```
sql_strings <- lapply(1:100, function(x){
  paste0("SELECT a.*, b.ln_yval FROM appo_01_t_all as a LEFT JOIN df_01_Z",
         # The following line takes care of the leading zeros, assuming 4 digits are needed.
         sprintf("%04d", x), 
         " as b on a.week=b.week") 
  })

your_function <- function(string){
  df <- sqldf(string)
  df <- df[,-2]
  df <- df[order(df$week),]
  ts_df <- ts(df$ln_yval, freq=52)
  mod_01 <- HoltWinters(ts_df, alpha = NULL, beta = NULL, gamma = NULL, seasonal = c("additive"))
  fcst_tab <- predict(mod_01, 4, prediction.interval = FALSE)
  return(fcst_tab)
}

outcomes <- lapply(sql_strings, your_function)
```

Here, `outcomes` is a list of whatever your function returns for each string.

If you need to keep each dataframe for anything else, you can also break that function up into multiple parts. For instance,

```
get_dataframes <- function(string){
  df <- sqldf(string)
  df <- df[,-2]
  df <- df[order(df$week),]
  return(df)}

get_predictions <- function(df)
  ts_df <- ts(df$ln_yval, freq=52)
  mod_01 <- HoltWinters(ts_df, alpha = NULL, beta = NULL, gamma = NULL, seasonal = c("additive"))
  fcst_tab <- predict(mod_01, 4, prediction.interval = FALSE)
  return(fcst_tab)
}

dataframes <- lapply(sql_strings, get_dataframes)
predictions <- lapply(dataframes, get_predictions)
```

Comment: ok i've understood the creation of the sql string. But how can integrate the other lines of code that I've written above? I am new with R so I am not sure how to go on. I mean, I have to create different databases and I should run the holwtinter model for n times

Comment: yes it's much clearer. I need to keep each dataframe, so I've just tried the second codes and I guess it's working!! thank you very much. But how can I "extract" dataframe from predictions? I have something that is called "list of ..", but how can I create single dataframes?

Comment: `dataframes` is simply a list of dataframes. The first one corresponds to the first string, the second to the second, etc. If I was you, I would keep them in the list to keep the workspace somewhat clean. If you do want each of them out of the list, you can use `list2env(dataframes,globalenv())`. You may need to name each element first, for which you can use `setNames`.

Comment: Similarly, `predictions` is a list of predictions. The first element is for the first dataframe that is in `dataframes`, the second element for the second, etc. I'd suggest you play around with `apply` family of functions for a while to familiarize yourself with them. It will pay off if you continue using R.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your help! any suggestions for some theory/reference where I can study R and applications like these ones?

Comment: This is all about `functional programming with R`, I reckon. Whenever you find yourself repeating code, write a function instead.  `lapply` is a built-in function that simply iterates over an input and passes it to a function. So, this is probably covered in some base R tutorials.